# In SQL is it possible to have a Variable which represent database table which can be used in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I was looking at cleaning up a stored procedure in some SQL code.

Given are 2 tables in 2 different databases `[DatabaseA].dbo.MyTable` and `[DatabaseB].dbo.MyTable`. Is it possible to have a variable which represents these locations which can then be used further down in the stored procedure?

The location to be used is determined by a variable which is passed into the stored procedure. Something like the code below.

```
DECLARE @Location …

If (@InputVariable = 1)
BEGIN 
    @Location  =  [DatabaseA].dbo.MyTable
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    @Location  =  [DatabaseB].dbo.MyTable
END

BEGIN
    UPDATE @Location
    WHERE
    …
END
```

Comment: You have to use dynamic sql for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dynamic SQL like this

```
DECLARE @Location …
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)
If (@InputVariable = 1)
BEGIN 
        @Location  =  '[DatabaseA].dbo.MyTable'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        @Location  =  '[DatabaseB].dbo.MyTable'
    END

BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 
    'UPDATE '+@Location+
    ' WHERE
    … '
END
EXECUTE (@SQL)
```

Comment: You would probably have to put the `[DatabaseA].dbo.MyTable` into single quotes, to assign it to a `varchar(max)` variable....

Comment: Thanks. Editied now. Just copy/pasted the OP's code :)

Comment: Thanks I tried the Dynamic SQL out and it works and solves my issue. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @InputVariable INT = 2


DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N' UPDATE ' + CASE WHEN @InputVariable = 1 THEN  QUOTENAME('DatabaseA')
                              ELSE QUOTENAME('DatabaseB') END + '.[dbo].[MyTable] '
          + N' SET Column = SomeValue'
          + N' WHERE some_condition'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
```

Comment: In Your Query it will always goes to **DatabaseB** as you are intializing the **@InputVariable** with **2**

Comment: It was only for demo purpose